# Feature importance using random forest vs. SHAP

Tags: feature-selection, random-forest, shap, feature-importances

I recently came across SHAP while looking for feature-importance methods. To use SHAP, first a model needs to be created, and then based on the predictions made by the model, SHAP values are calculated.

If I use a random forest model and then calculate the SHAP values, how much is the role of the model accuracy? If the model accuracy is not very good (50-60%), can SHAP values be considered reliable? Or if the model accuracy is good (>90%), why SHAP is used if random forest can provide me the feature importance?

Could someone explain the role of model accuracy while considering SHAP for determining feature importance?

Comment: Note that it is **always** a crappy idea to ask a crappy model for its feature importance. Now the other question is: what is a good model - the answer might be that you need to consider cost sensitivity ... But that depends on your business case

Comment: @Ggjj11 makes sense. So my point was if I have a good model, why shouldn't I believe in RF's feature importance? SHAP algorithm may be superior to RF but still, it's built on RF predictions.

Comment: Well there is 2 main ways of RF feature importances 1) default in sklearn is the Split-Feature importance which was shown to be bad, also due to interaction with the cardinality of a feature 2) the other one is the OOB feature importance which was reported to be much better. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15821880/12229416